# Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' java database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, string, integer

I've connected this program to my database, and everytime that I try to run it it shows me this error:

```
Selecione id da Encomenda: 
3
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not  supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation  does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

My imports

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

I have a few more queries just like that one but with `VARCHAR` and those work fine.

The Column `ENCOMENDAS` inside the table `DETALHES_ENCOMENDA`  is a INTEGER type like a ID, I already tried a lot of things but not even one worked

Can you guys help me?

Thanks!

```
try {

       BufferedReader in;
       in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ));
       System.out.print("\nConsultar lista de artigos de uma encomenda.\n");
       System.out.print("\nSelecione id da Encomenda: \n");
       String NR = in.readLine();


       Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/loja_inf/","luis","admin");
       c.setAutoCommit(false);
       Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
       String query =   " SELECT QUANTIDADE, IDPRODUTO, TIPOPRODUTO, FABRICANTE, MODELO, PRECO " +
                        " FROM DETALHES_ENCOMENDA " +
                        " INNER JOIN PRODUTOS " +
                        " ON DETALHES_ENCOMENDA.PRODUTO = PRODUTOS.IDPRODUTO " +
                        " WHERE ENCOMENDA = '"+ NR +"' ";

       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
       System.out.println( "Artigos da encomenda nº:" + NR);
       System.out.println( "---------------------------------------");
       while ( rs.next() ) {
           String FABRICANTE = rs.getString("FABRICANTE");
           String MODELO = rs.getString("MODELO");
           String PRECO = rs.getString("PRECO");
           String TIPOPRODUTO = rs.getString("TIPOPRODUTO");
           int QUANTIDADE = rs.getInt("QUANTIDADE");
           int IDPRODUTO = rs.getInt("IDPRODUTO");
           if( rs.wasNull() )
               System.out.println(  "A Encomenda nº:" + NR + " não existe.");
           else
               System.out.println("Id Produto: " + IDPRODUTO + " Tipo de Produto " + TIPOPRODUTO + " Fabricante: " + FABRICANTE + " Modelo: " + MODELO + " Preço: " + PRECO + " Quantidade: " + QUANTIDADE );
       }

       rs.close();
       stmt.close();
       c.close();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
       System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to verify that what you have in `NR` is a number and not a string that can't be used as a number.

```
int num = Integer.parseInt( NR );
```

You have a catch-all statement below, so if you get `NumberFormatException` in that statement, it will be caught by it. But of course, you can add an internal `catch` to handle the situation and ask the user for a new input, if you wish.

The next stage is *not to use single quotes*. Instead of:

```
                    " WHERE ENCOMENDA = '"+ NR +"' ";
```

You have to use

```
                    " WHERE ENCOMENDA = "+ num +" ";
```

Without the single quotes that tell the database system that this is the string `'3'` instead of the number `3`. Use the `num` variable that contains the number you parsed earlier.

This should solve your problem. However, it is strongly recommended to [use a prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of trying to build queries directly from user inputs. Prepared statements protect you against all sorts of hacking attempts or plain user errors, and are also more efficient when you repeat the same query again and again.

Comment: Thank you so much! All I did was this

 " WHERE ENCOMENDA = "+ num +" ";

I swapped that and it works!! thank you one more time! I'll try to do the same but between two different prices :)